# That which comes before the "sequel"

Tags: meaning, etymology, single-word-requests

The word "sequel" comes from the the Latin word *sequela* which means "that which follows" This Latin word is formed of two parts, "sequi" which is "to follow", and a suffix to make it a noun,"-ela".

If "sequel" means a following work which continues the narrative of the main work, what is a work that is before the main work?

As in "*Little Men* is the sequel to *Little Women*, but its "***_*__**" is actually *Jo's boys*"

I don't like "prequel", because it is assuming the root word is "quel", which isn't the fact. The fact is that "sequel" came from "sequi", and "prequel" doesn't actually come from anything. I would like an alternative.

Does anyone have any suggestions for words referring to works predating the referred work other than prequel?

Comment: @Third Idiot: this really sounds like [peeving](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)…

Comment: @F'x, I'm not peeving about grammar. I am asking for a word, and I do not wish it to be prequel, because I saw there was reason for not using it, and I gave an explaination why I didn't want to use it, so can someone give me an alternative?.

Comment: @Third Idiot, that reason is wrong, I think...

Comment: @Third Idiot: several people (including myself) have done so. And sentences like “prequel isn't actually correct”, “doesn't actually come from anything” and “was basically made up and informal” do sound like peeving to me.

Comment: Prequel sounds like a portmanteau to me. If so - it's perfectly correct. Although I've never heard or saw it used outside TV shows or fiction.

Comment: A portmanteau? If it was that, I would have accepted it more. Sadly, I don't think it is.

Comment: There may be peeving in the context of the question, but its core is "what is an alternative to *prequel* used by those who do not use *sequel*?", a real question. Though a minority, there is a significant group of people refusing to use *prequel* for reasons we all know. What alternatives are there? I use *predecessor* and *prelude* where appropriate. I may use *prequel* informally but I'm not a huge fan. Language is not only about utility: it's also about style.

Comment: Oh, these indignant comments were probably in reply to an earlier version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "precedent work", although more people will understand what you mean if you say "prequel".

Comment: I really like this term.

Answer (score 14):

1. ***Prequel* is not “wrong”**: it is widely used since the 1960’s and, as such, is documented in dictionaries (“a story or movie containing events that precede those of an existing work”, says *NOAD*). Because it is formed by merging the prefix *pre-* and *sequel*, rather than being directly derived from Latin roots, does not make it “wrong”, or *impure*, or *evil*, or whatever term with a moral connotation.
2. Latin doesn't have a single root for “come before”, leaving us with *[praecedo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praecedo)* or *[praevenio](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praevenio)*. Both roots have English decendents, namely *precedent* and ***prevenient***. The latter is probably the closest to what you want (but it's an adjective, not a noun):

> **prevenient** (adjective, formal)
>   preceding in time or order; antecedent: *John Wesley referred to God’s work in the unconverted as prevenient grace*.

---

Let's see a real use case:

> [image: quote]
>   – Have you seen the Star Wars prequel trilogy? That's badass CGI!
>   – I enjoyed the original trilogy, but I don't think very highly of Lucas’ prevenient story arc.

---

If you don't want to sound pedant and still want to avoid *prequel*, there are a number of alternative wordings such as *preceding opus* (or *work*).

Comment: Just because it was used widely in the 1960s doesn't remove the fact that it is an incorrect way of forming a word. It is assuming that "se-" is a prefix meaning "after",therefore can be replaced with "pre" This is obviously not true, and hence incorrect.

Comment: @Third Idiot: I'm not sure where you got the idea that there *can* be an "incorrect" way to form words to begin with. The whole point of neologisms is that they can be created out of nowhere, ignoring any and all rules, real or imagined. "*I* don't *like* it" is not the same as "*It* is *incorrect*". That's not how language works.

Comment: Oh, thanks Reg, that was the thing I should have written. Then maybe people would have plied me with suggestions, instead of proving "prequel" is correct!

Comment: [Wikipedia's definition of prequel](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Prequel) matches my intuition about "prequel" which is that a prequel is only a prequel if it was made after the original. That is, "The Phantom Menace" is a prequel but "A New Hope" is not. "A New Hope" is the predecessor of "The Empire Strikes Back" and not its prequel.

Answer (score 8):

Your explanation would be technically right but it's wrong and I'll try to explain why.

The word is **Prequel**, like the others said. Sequel might originally come from the Latin word *sequi*, but sequel has been absorbed by English and doesn't obey Latin constructions anymore, so using Latin might not be right and this is the case.

I'll give you a similar example: the word "Watergate" was originally the term used for a famous scandal in United States. The term was taken from a building that was named like that, where interceptions were made.
Years later, another scandal in the U.S. was named "Sexgate". The explanation is that every scandal now takes the suffix *-gate* that per se means *nothing*. But now it has acquired the meaning "scandal regarding..." or something similar.

Same goes for *sequel*, where *-quel* became a sort of suffix in the cinema field; therefore, **prequel** is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I hand it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe plain simple "the previous work" (or novel or article or pretty much anything you need)?

> In his previous article on sea monsters in fantasy campaigns Mr. Knowitall presented us with several fascinating - and dreadfull - life forms, found in deepest corners of the Ocean.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "original".

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prequel)

- Hannibal Rising (2007)
- Red Dragon (2002)

Are called prequels

- The Silence of the Lambs (1991) Is the **original**

A fictitious Return of Hannibal (2015) would be a sequel.

Comment: I am assuming that this answer is addressing the title, which asks what comes before a sequel. The body of the question, however, is asking for another word for prequel.

Comment: Why would *The Silence of the Lambs* be the original?  It was the sequel to the 1986 *Manhunter*, which was later remade as  *Red Dragon*, a more faithful version of the book that despite the stronger cast (the stellar Ed Norton replacing pre- *CSI* William Petersen and Anthony Hopkins again replacing, and respelling, Brian Cox as Hannibal Lecktor/Lector in the role he made famous) just wasn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

The word is "prequel". The fact that it has no authenticity in Latin is irrelevant.

If you insist on classically-formed words, the best I can think of is "predecessor", but this is less precise, as it does not indicate whether it precedes in internal or external chronology.

Comment: It's not prequel. A prequel is a work that was written after the original, but contains events that occurred before the events in the original.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, there's no problem with "prequel", but perhaps "prelude" also fits the bill and has the roots you're after.

Comment: Sort of like this: Wagner's *Ring* cycle, made up of four operas, consists of a prelude and a trilogy.

Answer (score -1):

In popular literature and movie culture I've come across `prequel`, but I don't know if that stands the tests of linguistics, etymology and valid sources and references often required here.

Comment: Ouch, did you edit your question? I did not see the last two paragraphs before I started my answer. I did not see Prequel in your question.

Comment: Nah, it was always there.

Comment: But I did change a bit of the last two paragraphs so that it wouldn't offend anyone.

Comment: Must be time for me to get some sleep....

Comment: Yawn... me too! Got to wake up at 5.30 tomorrow